# Java Application runs much slower in console than from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, console, ram

I am having a very strange problem with Java that I have been unable to make any progress in fixing. I have designed a small application for generating and viewing simple fractals, it is part of a coursework. When I run the code from Eclipse it runs very quickly, generally using <5% of my processor and acting generally very responsive.

However when I run this same program from the windows command line, after compiling it of course, it runs much more slowly. It uses about 20% of the processor and if I was to put a figure on it I would say it runs about 10x slower, and is generally unusable. I have done a good bit of research on this problem and it hasn't been easy to come across relevant information, it certainly doesn't seem to be a common bug. The times it has been asked before differ from my situation in that people are writing an excessive amount to the console, which causes the slowdown. I am not printing anything to the console.

The process started by Eclipse when the code is run uses up to about 700mb of RAM. The code ran from the console uses up to about 70mb. I tried running it with a greater heap size, which did increase the RAM the process uses but did virtually nothing to increase the performance.

I would really appreciate it if anybody could help with this issue, I am tearing my hair out here.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Make sure the JDK used by Eclipse is the same JDK used from command line.  Also, make sure classpath only contains the jars you need and does not include any networked drives or paths.

Comment: I am using the same JDK in Eclipse and at the command line. The classpath also only contains the default .jars and there are no external files associated with the project.